# Magento fortis theme - Footer change

Tags: magento, footer

***Magento Fortis Theme*** has a option of automatic width calculation.

I've 5 columns in footer

**Col1(12-2) - Col2(12-2) - Col3(12-2) - Col4(12-2) - Col5(12-2)**

All above column has by default 12-2 width of column width.

I've disabled to automatic width calculation from backend and I want column structure like following.

**Col1(12-2) - Col2(12-2) - Col3(12-2) - Col4(12-2) - Col5(12-4)**

I've checked footer.phtml,layout.xml but not getting any clue to change width of columns or making it custom.

Any help, suggestion??